Как добавлять товар в корзину php mysql?
Я понимаю, что создаётся для этого отдельное бд с user_id, product_id. Но не буду же я добавлять каждый id товара в product_id? Получится какая-то каша по типу 01234... и, соответственно, вывести товары по такому id не выйдет.
Облазил весь ютуб и браузер, но нужного срособа не нашёл связанного с БД.
Подскажите кто делал корзину на бд, как сделать подобный функционал? Или же есть какие-то видеоуроки?

Вы уже неделю по разным форумам мыкаетесь, и за это время даже вопрос задать толком не смогли. Вам нужны не уроки "как корзину делать", а букварь "как делают таблицы в базе данных". Если бы вы понимали, что такое таблица в БД, то не писали бы ересь про "каждый id товара в product_id".  каждый id товара добавляется в свою строку. Добавил пользователь три товара в корзину - в таблице три строки. Добавил еще один 2 товара - в таблице 5. И так далее. Это самые основы работы с БД, но вы и их не знаете.
